# Set class method as OpenSSL callbacks

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm writing a class that takes care of encryption related work using OpenSSL. How do I specify class' methods for PSK related callbacks?

*SSL_set_psk_find_session_callback* and
*SSL_set_psk_use_session_callback*

Tried std::bind, but got compiler error:

```
SSL_set_psk_find_session_callback(ssl, bind(&OpenSslHandler::psk_find_session_cb, this));
```

> Error C2664   'void SSL_set_psk_find_session_callback(SSL
>   *,SSL_psk_find_session_cb_func)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Binder' to 'SSL_psk_find_session_cb_func'

EDIT: There are multiple instances of OpenSSLHandler called from multiple threads - to handle simultaneous connections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each connection has a unique `SSL *` dedicated to that connection.  That value gets passed to your callback functions.

You can't specify a class instance to use to make instance method calls on via the OpenSSL interface - it's strictly C and not C++.

Use a `std::map<SSL *,OpenSslHandler *>` or similar data structure in an `extern "C"` callback function to find the proper class instance to use to make instance method calls on.  Just make sure to properly mutex-protect your data structure.

Alternatively, you can use [`SSL_set_ex_data()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_set_ex_data.html) when you get your `SSL *` connection, and set an `OpenSslHandler *` pointer to the `OpenSslHandler` instance for that `SSL *` connection, then use `SSL_get_ex_data()` to retrieve the pointer - again in an `extern "C"` callback function.

To use get/set methods, you first need to create a unique index by calling [`SSL_get_ex_new_index()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_get_ex_new_index.html). The returned integer index can be stored in a static class variable. It is unique across your application and can be used with all SSL objects to get/set Ex_Data.

Comment: SSL_set_ex_data() looks like the right approach, but the documentation isn't very clear. I'm supposed to create an Index using SSL_get_ex_new_Index. Now the issue is how do I pass this index to callback, so I can use it in SSL_get_ex_data()?

Comment: @tunafish24 You know the value used for the index when you called `SSL_set_ex_data()` for your `OpenSslHandler *`.  Per the documentation:  "The user must supply a unique index which they can subsequently use to retrieve the data using `SSL*_get_ex_data()`."

Comment: Documentation says to use SSL_get_ex_new_index() to create a unique index. However, since it uses the SSL object, I'm assuming the index is specific to that SSL? If so, this means I need to somehow access that unique index in the callback so I can call SSL_get_ex_data()

Answer (score 0):

By convention, most libraries allow you to pass arbitrary user data to callbacks, but this does not seem to be the case here.

Some alternatives:

- Store a pointer in a thread-local, global or static variable. The last two are only safe if there is only ever one `OpenSslHandler` in the program,
- Store a (shared) pointer to the `OpenSslHandler` in a `std::map<SSL_CTX*, OpenSslHandler*>`. In your `SSL_psk_find_session_cb_func`, recover the `SSL_CTX` pointer via [`SSL_get_SSL_CTX`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_SSL_CTX.html) and use that to look up the `OpenSslHandler` in the map.

Comment: Updated my question, basically there are multiple instances of OpenSslHandler called from multiple threads